# about mod_rtmp freeswitch

Tags: flash, sip, freeswitch

is it possible to send video streaming to freeswitch on flash client?
I changed source code freeswitch.mxml like this

```
outgoingNetStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
outgoingNetStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatus);
outgoingNetStream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
★outgoingNetStream.attachCamera(cam);
outgoingNetStream.attachAudio(mic);
outgoingNetStream.publish("publish", "live”);
```

but i got this error

```
2014-07-17 17:46:48.068713 [ERR] rtmp.c:875 WTF 2048 128
2014-07-17 17:46:48.068713 [ERR] rtmp.c:878 Protocol error: exceeding max AMF packet size
```

so I wonder if I will change #define AMF_MAX_SIZE 2048 value in mod_rtmp.h file…

and one more question.

is it possible to incoming call from sip to flash client?

I tried to call from linphone-iphone, but i got error like this.

```
USER_NOT_REGISTERED
```

Should I change config file like below?

```
rtmp_contact profile/user@domain[/[!]nickname]
<action application="bridge" data="${rtmp_contact($${rtmp_profile}/${dialed_ext}@$${domain})}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got same problem and filled the ticket in freeswitch Jira.
They replied: "I'm not sure video was ever tested or supported using RTMP, So work would probably need to be done to make it possible"

https://jira.freeswitch.org/browse/FS-6885